# extending existing validator and only set some options

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator, class-validator

My database column is of type **double precision** (from the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/datatype-numeric.html))

> double precision  8 bytes variable-precision, inexact 15 decimal digits precision

Using class-validator I want to make a precision check

```
@IsNumber()
/* precision check */
public myValue: number;
```

The `IsDecimal` decorator might help here, so `@IsDecimal({ decimal_digits: '15' })` might do the trick. I would have to use this decorator for multiple fields, is there a way to extend the existing decorator and just pass in the `decimal_digits` option? I don't think it makes sense to reinvent the wheel. It would be nice if I could inherit the validation but set the precision to **less or equal to 15**.

Currently I created my own decorator

```
@ValidatorConstraint()
class IsDoublePrecisionConstraint implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
    public validate(value: any): boolean {
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            if (value % 1 === 0) {
                return true;
            }

            const valueText: string = value.toString();
            const valueSegments: string[] = valueText.split('.');
            const decimalDigits: string = valueSegments[1];

            return decimalDigits.length <= 15;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public defaultMessage(args: ValidationArguments): string {
        return `${args.property} must have less than or equal to 15 decimal digits.`;
    }
}

export function IsDoublePrecision() {
    return (object: Record<string, any>, propertyName: string) => {
        registerDecorator({
            target: object.constructor,
            propertyName,
            validator: IsDoublePrecisionConstraint,
        });
    };
}
```

but I'm not sure if this one is able to handle every case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't found any example about extending a existed decorator of `class-validator`, but the `IsDecimal` just is a normal property decorator, then we can use it as a property decorator.

My idea is creating a "normal" property decorator and call `IsDecimal` in this decorator with `decimal_digits` option.

```
// function as a const
export const IsDoublePrecision = () => { // use decorator factory way
  return (target: object, key: string) => { // return a property decorator function
    IsDecimal({ decimal_digits: '15' })(target, key); // call IsDecimal decorator
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@IsNumber()
/* precision check */
@IsDoublePrecision()
public myValue: number;
```

Comment: thank you very much, would you mind explaining the shorthand syntax here? `IsDecimal({ decimal_digits: '15' })(target, key);` I've never seen it :)

Comment: and second, I tested this by passing in various values like `48.4445`, `48.444546845645878847545456487458948`, `48.123456789112345` but every time I get this error message :( "value is not a valid decimal number."

Comment: sorry to bother you, I also created my own decorator and updated my question

Comment: @Question3r Too many think need to explain for my code, but in sort, `IsDecimal` is a decorator factory, it will return a decorator when you call `IsDecimal()`. A property decorator will create some `metadata` for the class, metadata stores in for about property name, and validation type... it will be use in `validate` function of `class-validator`. Call `(target, key)` is applying logic of `IsDecimal ` for the class what uses `IsDoublePrecision`.

Comment: I don't know exactly spec of `IsDecimal`, but you will get the same error when you use `@IsDecimal({ decimal_digits: '15' })` instead of `IsDoublePrecision ` with the same test cases. It will pass when `myValue` is a like number string.

Comment: Good idea when you do your logic by yourself.